# Page_Load() being called multiple times(once for every JS file used in page) and Page.IspostBack is FALSE

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-ajax

I read This question and answers

[ASP.Net: Page_Load() being called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094954/asp-net-page-load-being-called-multiple-times)

In my case, Page_Load is fired 3 times and it is not "postback".
Also, the query string is wrong.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

       <script src="/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>

    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
  <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server" LoadingPanelID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1">
 /telerik:RadAjaxPanel>
     <telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel ID="RadAjaxLoadingPanel1" runat="server"     >
    </telerik:RadAjaxLoadingPanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Form.Action = Request.RawUrl;
            if (Request.QueryString["s"] != null) 
           //do something with querystring
        }
}
```

QueryString value is true on first time.(7 for example)

on the second time, page_load fired it is 7/scrips/jquery.js

on 3rd it's 7/script/bootstrap.js

is this normal?

Comment: down vote on the first second after posting?without any comment! why?

Comment: Do you have javascript that submits page on the page? how does the form look?

Comment: @LasseEdsvik No.
There is an update panel (RadAjaxPanel) on the form, A repeater, and Sqldatasource.

Comment: you have not provided any of the page markup that may lead us to answer your question.  Is there any js code on the page itself?

Comment: @Kevbo I removed all controls from page now. and it is same

Comment: missing < at "/telerik:RadAjaxPanel>" but I assume thats corrected in your code

Comment: @LasseEdsvik It was a mistake made here. the original file was correct.
I deleted the file, create with same copied code from the previous file, and it is working now. mystery not solved. but problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
It was a URL rewriting problem!
Sorry for not giving enough information! I have forgotten all about URL rewriting because this part was done a long time ago!